# What test to compare pre and post test both Likert scale (1 to 5)

Tags: likert

What test to compare pre and post test both Likert scale (1 to 5).  N=5.  Have looked at t-test, Wilcoxon and sign test. Don't know if assumptions for the tests are met.

Answer (score -1):

The Friedman test for correlated data is pretty standard for comparing this type of data. The sample size of 5 is pretty small, so look for an `exact` method of some kind.